# airflow.decorators not being recognized

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver

I am a new user of Airflow. I successfully set up the airflow locally.
But when I try to import modules such as `from airflow.decorators` or `airflow.operators.pythonOperators` I receive an error as `Import could not be resolved`.

Below is the screenshot of my situation.

[image]

Receiving the same error on my localhost web-server:

[image]

Please help me out, as I am entirely new to apache-airflow

Edit:
My current version of airflow is already `2.3.4`

Comment: Are you using a conda environment or python virtual environment ?

Answer (score 0):

Airflow `decorators` are added in the version 2.2.0, you need just to upgrade your Airflow version

```bash
AIRFLOW_VERSION=2.3.4 # the version you want to use, it should be >= 2.2.0
PYTHON_VERSION="$(python --version | cut -d " " -f 2 | cut -d "." -f 1-2)"
CONSTRAINT_URL="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-${AIRFLOW_VERSION}/constraints-${PYTHON_VERSION}.txt"
pip install "apache-airflow==${AIRFLOW_VERSION}" --constraint "${CONSTRAINT_URL}"
```

Comment: Hey, my current version is already 2.3.4